# Set alignment of content within a div that sits inline with another div

Tags: html, css

I have a page with two divs side by side in a one third to two third split. These are contained within a parent div. One of my divs has an image and what I want to do is have the ability to vertically align this image either to the top, middle or bottom of the parent div, the height of which is defined by the amount of text in the second div. Ideally, I'd like to be able to add a class to the image or to content-a that would set the alignment.

https://jsfiddle.net/y9mLr5xv/1/

```
<style type="text/css">
  section {
    padding: 40px 0 40px;
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-family: sans-serif;
  }

  .inner {
    width: 95%;
    max-width: 1040px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }

  .section-body {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
  }

  .content-a {
    width: 32.7%;
    float: left;
  }

  .content-b {
    width: 62.1%;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 4.2%;
  }

  h3 {
    margin: 0;  
  }
</style>

<section class="main">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="section-header">
      <div class="content">
        <h1>
          Header here
        </h1>
        <p class="strap">
          Strapline would go here
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section-body">
  <div class="content-a">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  </div>
  <div class="content-b">
    <h3>
      Title here
    </h3>
    <p>
      A bit of text here. Not sure what it would say but it be here. A bit of text here. Not sure what it would say but it be here. A bit of text here. Not sure what it would say but it be here. A bit of text here. Not sure what it would say but it be here. A bit of text here. Not sure what it would say but it be here.
    </p>
    <ul>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
    </ul>
    <p>
      A bit of text here. Not sure what it would say but it be here. A bit of text here. Not sure what it would say but it be here. A bit of text here. Not sure what it would say but it be here. A bit of text here. Not sure what it would say but it be here. A bit of text here. Not sure what it would say but it be here.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I'd suggest using Bootstrap3. You could use 'row' for header part, .col-xs-4 for left side, col-xs-8 for right side + img-responsive for the image. Then just carefully use 'flex' and 'flex-direction: column'. In general it's not good to mix 'flex' with bootstrap, but in this case, it should be fine (you could try also Bootstrap4, reportedly it supports 'flex' display better than previous version). And for top/middle/bottom align you could simply use flex-start/center/flex-end (like [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_align-items&preval=stretch))

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use `display: table-cell`

http://jsfiddle.net/440d1f96/

with html:

```
<div class="area vertical-top">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/150/cats">
</div>

<div class="area">
  <p>lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>
```

and css:

```
.area {
    background: red;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.vertical-bottom {
      vertical-align: bottom;
}

.vertical-middle {
      vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Looks good. Found another solution using `display: flex`. Thoughts?

Comment: Depends what browser support you need: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution using `display: flex`

https://jsfiddle.net/johnthomson92/y9mLr5xv/2/

HTML:

```
<section class="main">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="section-header">
      <div class="content">
        <h1>
          Header here
        </h1>
        <p class="strap">
          Strapline would go here
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section-body">
      <div class="content-a top">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
      </div>
      <div class="content-b">
        <h3>
          Title here
        </h3>
        <p>
          A bit of text here. Not sure what it would say but it be here. A bit of text here. Not sure what it would say but it be here. A bit of text here. Not sure what it would say but it be here. A bit of text here. Not sure what it would say but it be here. A bit of text here. Not sure what it would say but it be here.
        </p>
        <ul>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
        </ul>
        <p>
          A bit of text here. Not sure what it would say but it be here. A bit of text here. Not sure what it would say but it be here. A bit of text here. Not sure what it would say but it be here. A bit of text here. Not sure what it would say but it be here. A bit of text here. Not sure what it would say but it be here.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
section {
  padding: 40px 0 40px;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.inner {
  width: 95%;
  max-width: 1040px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.section-body {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.strap {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.content-a {
  width: 32.7%;
  float: left;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.top {
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.middle {
  align-items: center;
}

.bottom {
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.content-b {
  width: 62.1%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 4.2%;
}

p {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

h3 {
  margin: 0;  
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**try this it may help you to achieve your goal**

```
.content-a img {
  width: 45%;
  float: left;
}

.content-b {
  width: 45%;
  float: right;
//  margin-left: 4.2%;
}
```